# JSON Form.append

Tags: javascript, json

What is wrong with my code?

```
var form = $('#actor-form');

      form.append('<input name ="actor-id" type="hidden" value="' + datum.id + '">');
      form.append('<input name ="actor-email" type="hidden" value="' + datum.email + '">');
     })

})( jQuery );
```

It keeps throwing errors, should it be???

```
var form = $('#actor-form');

      form.append('<input name ="actor-id" type="hidden" value="' + datum.id + '">
                   <input name ="actor-email" type="hidden" value="' + datum.email + '">');
     })

})( jQuery );
```

I'm not sure.  Please help!

Comment: we can't guess what the errors are, can you give us a hint? :)

Comment: Please state what error you get in console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If type is hidden then you can't test. i changed type as text to see if it is working or not. has to check your datum object also once for sure.

```
$(function(){
    var form = $('#actor-form');

    var datum = {};
        datum.id = 1001;
        datum.email = "welcome@gmail.com";

    form.append('<input name="actor-id" type="text" value="' + datum.id + '">');
    form.append('<input name="actor-email" type="text" value="' + datum.email + '">');
});
```

Comment: function (obj, datum{}) {

          var form = $('#actor-form');
          var datum = {};

          form.append('<input name ="actor-id" type="hidden" value="' + datum.id + '">');
          form.append('<input name ="actor-email" type="hidden" value="' + datum.email + '">');
         })thanks this worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    // here initialize datum variable 
    var form = $('#actor-form');
    form.append('<input name ="actor-id" type="hidden" value="' + datum.id + '">');
    form.append('<input name ="actor-email" type="hidden" value="' + datum.email + '">');
})( jQuery );
```